# problem running a .sh file on cronjob file using docker

Tags: bash, docker, cron

I am new with cron job and docker. I am trying to run a cron job in my docker container to upload database backup every day.

If I put echo in my cron file it shows the message on my container logs but the bash file is not working.  I attached my cron file and docker file. Can anyone help out if my syntax is wrong or I am missing something. I already checked the existed solutions and it looks same. Thanks

My cron file:

```
* * * * * bash /backup.sh -u mongodb://user:pass@mongo:27017 >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

My docker file:

```
       FROM mongo:latest
       RUN apt-get update
       RUN apt-get install -y cron
       RUN apt-get install -y curl
       RUN apt-get install -y zip

       ADD /script/container_cronjob /etc/cron.d/container_cronjob
       RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/container_cronjob
       RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

       WORKDIR /usr/src/app

       COPY ./script/backup.sh /backup.sh

       RUN chmod +x /backup.sh

       #CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log

       CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "chmod 644 /etc/cron.d/container_cronjob && cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log"]
```

My backup.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "`date`    Starting MongoDB backup...";

while getopts u:d: flag
do
  case "${flag}" in
    u) uri=${OPTARG};;
    d) dest=${OPTARG};;
  esac
done

# Get the current date and time
CURRENT_DATE=`date +%y%m%d-%H%M%S`;

DESTPATH="$dest/$CURRENT_DATE";
echo  "`date`    Backup destination is $DESTPATH";
echo $uri
# Create the destination directory and backup the database
mkdir -p $DESTPATH;
mongodump --uri=$uri -o $DESTPATH --gzip


# Set your nextcloud username and password
username="user";
password="pass";

# Set your mongodb path running on your system
mongodbPath="http://nextcloud/";

# Nextcloud path
nextcloudPath="remote.php/dav/files/";

# Concat username with the nextcloud path
nextcloudPath=$nextcloudPath$username;
nextcloudPath=$nextcloudPath"/";

# Concat the mongodb path with the nextcloud path
uriPath=$uriPath$mongodbPath;
uriPath=$uriPath$nextcloudPath;
uriPath=$uriPath$CURRENT_DATE;
uriPath=$uriPath".zip"

echo $uriPath

#craete zip for the backup folder
zip -r $DESTPATH.zip $DESTPATH

# Upload backup zip file to nextcloud
curl -X PUT -u $username:$password $uriPath -T $DESTPATH.zip

echo "`date`    MongoDB backup completed.";
exit 0
```

My Docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"

services:

  mongo:
    container_name: "mongo"
    image: "mongo:latest"
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=user
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass

  nextcloud:
    container_name: "nextcloud"
    image: "nextcloud:latest"
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/www/html/data
      - ./config:/var/www/html/config

  backup:
    container_name: "backup"
    image: "0edb1970a1e6"
```

Comment: What's actually in the `backup.sh` script?  (It seems like it might be missing its "shebang" line, `#!/bin/sh` at the very beginning of the file; you shouldn't have to explicitly say `bash` to run it.)  How are you running the container?  (Are there volume mounts that potentially hide the script?)

Comment: Please copy and paste your crontab entry in fixed-point font, not proportional font, so that we can see the spaces properly. If the line really says `bash /backup.sh ...`, it would mean that your script is stored in the root directory (`/`), which is very unlikely.

Comment: My backup.sh file starts with         #!/bin/bash
my docker-compose file looks like this: version: "3"

services:
  mongo:
    container_name: "mongo"
    image: "mongo:latest"
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=user
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
  nextcloud:
    container_name: "nextcloud"
    image: "nextcloud:latest"
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/www/html/data
      - ./config:/var/www/html/config
  backup:
    container_name: "backup"
    image: "0edb1970a1e6"

Comment: @DavidMaze : Using `bash` explicitly is IMO not that bad. At least we can clearly see which shell is used to run the script.

Comment: Don't put code in you comment. It's virtually unreadable. Such information should go into your question. Also, if you really run your script with `bash ....`, the #! line does not matter.

Comment: I update my question and put all info in it. I hope its readable now

Comment: What is the meaning of _bash file is not working_? For debugging, I suggest that you change the crontab entry to run `bash -x /backup.sh ....` and that you redirect the stderr also to some log file (`2>>/var/log/cron_error.log`).

Comment: I mean bash file is not running from the cron file. If i put my bash file in my docker file with CMD command it works but only one time. I want it to run every day.

Comment: _is not running_ : You mean, it doesn't even get started? What happens if you run it manually from the command line? BTW, if cron can not start a program, it produces an error message, which should be written to `/var/log/syslog`. Did you check there?

Comment: And, just a silly idea (because the devil never sleeps): When you do a `crontab -l`, do you see the crontab? Also, where do you have installed that crontab - inside your docker, or on the host from where you run the docker?

Comment: I checked I dont have syslog on var/log/syslog path. I install cron on my container as you can see in my docker file.

Comment: cron is working if I write some echo statements, but when I write a command to run the bash file it show me nothing. To verify it if I go to my nextcloud to check if it upload the backup then there is no backup file. so I want to have a right command to run the bash file on my cron file OR if there is another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution

```
* * * * * root /backup.sh -u mongodb://mongo:27017 -d ./backup >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

I have to write root infront of the command so it can access the file correctly.
Just write the proper path where you store your file on the container.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).